# Hibernate Identity differences when moving from Oracle To Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am switching a Java application using Hibernate from Oracle to Postgres and encountering a issue with Id GeneratedValues.

The Domain objects have Ids configured like this:

```java
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
```

Under Oracle there was a sequence called "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" that provided this. I have created this sequence in Postgres like this:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 50000 CACHE 20   NO CYCLE ;
```

However, when persisting an object I'm getting an error of:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "hibernate_sequence"
```

I have tried:

- switching the "GenerationType" to "SEQUENCE"
- creating the sequence in lower case (hibernate_sequence)

But I get the same error in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure Hibernate to speak the PostgreSQL dialect of SQL.

In Oracle you get the next value of a sequence with a pseudo-column (`hibernate_sequence.nextval`), while in PostgreSQL you use a function (`nextval(hibernate_sequence)`). Using the Oracle syntax with PostgreSQL will cause the error you quote.

Comment: ok, but how is that done? I don't see the oracle version of that anywhere in the code.

Comment: I don't do Hibernate, but a web search turned up https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-dialect

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I had was not setting the `hibernate.dialect` property correctly.

It was

```xml
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
```

and changing it to

```xml
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"/>
```

fixed it and started using the correct sequence function as Laurenze Able pointed out